# SQL - Union all / Inner join (with where clauses)

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm trying to port a lot of old AS400 queries to SQL as I'm developing a GUI for reporting & updating records from the libraries in AS/400.

With that, I've encountered a query that has quite a few steps and the joining of tables is throwing me a little.

The below is a query that does what I want for retrieving data from two of the three physical files on the AS400.

```
select substr(clntpm,1,2) as clntwf, substr(pal#pm,1,10) as pal#wf, 
       substr(clsspm,1,2) as clsswf, clsqpm * 1 as clsqwf
from warpall
where locnpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
  and commpm <> 'ASSEMBLED PALLET'
  and clsqpm <> 0

union all

select substr(clntpq,1,2) as clntwf, substr(pal#pq,1,10) as pal#wf, 
       substr(clsspq,1,2) as clsswf, clsqpq * 1 as clsqwf
from warpalq
where clsqpq <> 0
```

Now I want to add a third table... As I understand, I want to do an inner join on the result of the above union.

```
select * from (
<old query>
) t9
inner join t3 on <field> where t3.field = t9.field
```

Is what I tried, but I'm clearly getting the syntax wrong as I get an error about the where clause being unexpected.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? DB2?

Comment: There is no column called `field` in the union statement.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select 
  * from (<old query>) as t9
inner join 
  t3 
on 
  t3.field = t9.field
```

Comment: Seems to have worked fine, just running some comparison to the as400 output

Thank you

Comment: you are welcome .
do accept my answer as correct one and vote it up ;)

Comment: Yes, your response did fix the issue I was having. Naturally I've encountered another, which makes me think Ive approached it wrong (Ive never written a sub-select before this one).

I can no longer join on warpall as it's aliased as t9 in the nested select statement.
I cant add it to t9 as it's not in warpalq so the union all will fail.

I guess I need to drop the union all and write a three stage select ?

Comment: @PureBluff . . . If this answers your question, you should answer it.  If you have another question, ask that as a question, not in a comment.